# What is the meaning of "The rate I'm going"?

Tags: meaning

In Angelina Jolie-directed movie *By The Sea* (2015), Vanessa taking sun bath and her husband writer, Roland, asked this question to her.

> Roland: Wanna go for a drive?
>
> Vanessa: I thought we agreed we weren't going anywhere  until you
>   wrote.
>
> Roland: **The rate I'm going**... Let's go for a drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes words that are obvious or understood in the context can be missed out.  This is called ellipsis.
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/ellipsis

"The rate I'm going", in this context, means "at the rate I'm going", i.e. "at the speed I'm going at", "at the speed I'm writing".

The implication is that he's writing so slowly, or progressing with his writing so slowly, that it will be a very long time before they can go for a drive (based on the principle originally set out)  so they may as well set that rule aside and just go for a drive anyway.

The meaning is along these lines:

> Vanessa: I thought we agreed we weren't going anywhere until you
>   wrote.
>
> Roland: [At] the rate I'm going, [that's going to take forever!]  Let's go for a drive.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, "the rate I'm going" would mean "speed":

> Considering the time it takes me to write, let's go for a drive instead.

From Google:

> A measure, quantity, or frequency, typically one measured against another quantity or measure.
>
> "The island has the lowest crime rate in the world"

Answer (score 0):

In that sentence, **The rate I'm going** is exactly a good synonymous for the word **Speed** as other members have said.

In that conversation, **The rate I'm going** has a form like this:

> With the rate/speed I'm going (writing) with, I don't think we'd be able to go for a drive.